# Custom gem `active_admin` in Ruby On rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, activeadmin

Currently, I am working on a project using gem `active_admin` to act as site admin. Now I receive a request like this:

On the admin page, there will be a new user type `super_admin`, this user can create many companies, each company will have a manager (also created by `super_admin`).

The manager of company A will login to the admin site (with the account created in step 1), you can only operate on the objects of company A, similar to company B, C, D ...

I do not know how to implement this logic with gem active_admin, can you give me suggestions on how to do or keywords to handle logic like this with active_admin gem?

Comment: Hi we're not a code writing service. we're here to help you once you've tried and got specific problems that need helping with.

Comment: show us your codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ActiveAdmin's [authorization adapter](https://activeadmin.info/13-authorization-adapter.html) to achieve this.

By defining your own authorization adapter, you can have a check in your `authorized?` method to see if the `subject` (the record that's being accessed) belongs to the `current_user`'s company and only return `true` if the user has access. This way, you can also limit certain actions to be only available for the super admin.

AcitveAdmin then uses your authorization adapter to only show the related records to the admins and they can only edit or delete those records.